# CSS Word-wrap on navbar

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm new to web technologies and I'm trying to build a navbar basically copying https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black as a learning tool. This worked fine, until I wanted to have an image with one of the buttons, as in the image at (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVVTC.jpg)

The image seems to cause the text to wordwrap. No image but a ton of text and the field just expands... As soon as there's an image there... it wraps. I've tried a whole bunch of different display styles on various elements... I tried putting the image and the text in the same span, which seemed to make sense to me... But I can't seem to figure out what part of css I'm not getting.

edit: the html part

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/account_image.svg" /> Bob Smith
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML which includes image?

Comment: Just added it. It's as simple as possible I think :)

Comment: Can I see your css as well?

Comment: It's exactly the same as in the link to w3schools :) Except img { max-height: 18pt; }

Comment: I can see it working when editing w3 editor. Added this line in `<ul>` at first

`<li><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/lTbVsVD.png" /> Bob smith</a></li>`

and 

`
li a img {
    height: 16px;
}
`

Comment: Yeah... it looks fine when I run it through JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9eu8z70/ No idea what's going on with my local copy. Thanks for  taking a look. I'll have to figure out the difference....

Comment: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Microsoft_Account.svg" Specitically this image for some reason. Probably because it's an svg?

Comment: If you paste it as snippet, we can inspect and try to help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t10jqmr7/ If I switch out that svg for a png, the "Home Game" goes on a single line... like I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fiddle updated with proper solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/t10jqmr7/1/

Added width to the `<img>` tag

Also I added clear-fixing the floating elements.